# How can I make my app runs offline ? I am using Firebase ,my app displays large texts and many pictures

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I am using Firebase, my app displays large texts and many pictures
I want to run offline and display this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore has its own [offline persistence mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), which for Android and Apple platforms, is enabled by default.

Regarding images, you can cache them on the user device using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: Hey Abdullah. Can I help with other information?